# PHP: Xpath query for classname and echo result

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I have this very simple HTML page (extract.html) with this content:

```
<html>
<body>
    <span class="price_value">
     20.50
    </span>

    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I want to get the value of class price_value (20.50) with this code:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("extract.html");
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$spaner = $finder->query("(//span[@class='price_value'])[1]");
print_r($spaner);
?>
```

However the only output i recieve is this:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )
```

Why is it not finding and printing the contents of the classname i specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function expects HTML string parameter, not an HTML file name. You're expected to use [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) function instead to load from HTML file :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("extract.html");
.....
```